# WSO2 EI analytics

Tags: xml, wso2, wso2-esb

I'm trying to fetch the `EI 6.5.0 analytics` for an API created in `EI`, but I'm unable to fetch the details or any statistics. I am able to find the respective API on the portal.

1. We have configured the `carbon.xml`, synapse.properties file based on the `WSO2` documents after running worker and dashboard, but no analytics is reflecting on the portal. I would request you to please explain the steps to fetch the EI analytics.
2. Error from analytics-dashboard

   > ERROR {org.wso2.msf4j.internal.MSF4JHttpConnectorListener} - Error in http connector listener org.wso2.transport.http.netty.contract.ServerConnectorException: Remote client closed the connection before initiating outbound response
3. Error Caused in analytics-worker

   > Caused by: org.wso2.extension.siddhi.store.rdbms.exception.RDBMSTableException: Error when preparing to execute query: 'SELECT MediatorStatAgg_YEARS.AGG_TIMESTAMP AS AGG_TIMESTAMP, MediatorStatAgg_YEARS.AGG_EVENT_TIMESTAMP AS AGG_EVENT_TIMESTAMP, MediatorStatAgg_YEARS.metaTenantId AS metaTenantId, MediatorStatAgg_YEARS.componentId AS componentId, MediatorStatAgg_YEARS.componentName AS componentName, MediatorStatAgg_YEARS.componentType AS componentType, MediatorStatAgg_YEARS.entryPoint AS entryPoint, MediatorStatAgg_YEARS.entryPointHashcode AS entryPointHashcode, MediatorStatAgg_YEARS.hashCode AS hashCode, MediatorStatAgg_YEARS.AGG_LAST_EVENT_TIMESTAMP AS AGG_LAST_EVENT_TIMESTAMP, MediatorStatAgg_YEARS.startTime AS startTime, MediatorStatAgg_YEARS.SHARD_ID AS SHARD_ID, MediatorStatAgg_YEARS.AGG_SUM_duration AS AGG_SUM_duration, MediatorStatAgg_YEARS.AGG_COUNT AS AGG_COUNT, MediatorStatAgg_YEARS.AGG_MIN_duration AS AGG_MIN_duration, MediatorStatAgg_YEARS.AGG_MAX_duration AS AGG_MAX_duration, MediatorStatAgg_YEARS.AGG_SUM_faultCount AS AGG_SUM_faultCount FROM MediatorStatAgg_YEARS WHERE (MediatorStatAgg_YEARS.SHARD_ID = ? ) ORDER BY MediatorStatAgg_YEARS.AGG_TIMESTAMP DESC LIMIT 1' on store: 'MediatorStatAgg_YEARS'

Comment: Is the database used for the  datasource defined in the deployment.yml(found in {EI_HOME}/wso2/analytics/conf/worker) with the name EI_ANALYTICS, was it an already existed database if so could you please point to a new database and run again?

Also if it's possible can you please share the complete logs for the both instances? in order to identify the problem clearly

Comment: i want to see analytics for EI,..we are not using any database as of now..this is some kind of inbuilt wso2 DB for which I'm getting confused..we created a api in EI and just wanted to see the analytics for that particular api..Already we followed an wso2 document, what they mentioned in wso2 Ei analytics.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that there is an issue with the databases that are used by the analytics profile. Could you please follow the steps below in order to recreate the database(Please do note that by following these steps the existing data will be lost)

1. Stop the Analytics worker profile that is running.
2. Delete the database files(EI_ANALYTICS.mv.db, EI_ANALYTICS.trace.db) which are located in the "{EI_HOME}/wso2/analytics/wso2/worker/database"
3. Restart the analytics worker profile.

I beleive this will probably fix your problem if not please provide the full logs for the issue.